# Redhat linux .bash_profile: line 12: syntax error: unexpected end of file

Tags: linux, bash, redhat

I use redhat linux and get problem: .bash_profile: line 12: syntax error: unexpected end of file
.Bashrc

```
# .bashrc

# User specific aliases and functions

export JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.6.0_45
export JRE_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.6.0_45/jre
export PATH=$PATH:/usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.6.0_45/bin:/usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.6.0_45/jre/bin

alias rm='rm -i'
alias cp='cp -i'
alias mv='mv -i'

# Source global definitions
if [ -f /etc/bashrc ]; then
. /etc/bashrc
fi
```

and Bash_profile

```
# .bash_profile

# Get the aliases and functions
if [ -f ~/.bashrc ]; then
. ~/.bashrc
fi

# User specific environment and startup programs
PATH=$PATH:$HOME/bin

export PATH
```

Could you tell me how to fix this problem? 
Thanks

Comment: Do either of those files have DOS line-endings? See point one on the bash tag [wiki](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/bash/info).

Comment: @EtanReisner thanks for your help.

Comment: Was that the problem?

Comment: I use dos2unix bash file to solved problem :)